# What is the correct way to str_replace until the end of string in PHP?

Tags: php, str-replace

If I have a string like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/myPDF.pdf" rel="">myPDF12345431234</a>
```

what would be the proper PHP function call to str_replace so that everything after " " rel=.... " is replaced with nothing/blank?

For further clarity, The value in between the link tags is dynamic and unknown, so I can't call it.

I'm looking for something like:

```
$oldstring = array('<a href="', '" rel="" *until the end_of_string* ');
$replacewith = array=('', '');

$newstring = str_replace($oldstring, $replacewith, $URL);
```

What is the proper way to get everything after the URL (quotation mark til the end of the string) to be replaced with nothing?

Comment: use a PCRE regex system such as [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is handled by regular expressions. The following replaces everything from rel="" to the end of the string.

```
$newstring = preg_replace('/ rel="".*$/','',$oldstring);
```

The .* means "everything" and $ means "end of string". I added a space before rel because I assume you want to drop that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_match:

```
preg_match("/(\<a href\=\\".*\\")\srel/", "<a href="http://example.com/myPDF.pdf" rel="">myPDF12345431234</a>", $output_array);
Var_dump($output_array);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fqQ

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're actually looking for is the **substring** of your current string up until the end of your `rel` attribute.

`$newstring = substr($oldstring, 0, strpos($oldstring, 'rel=""'));`